# Сжатие цветов с помощью побитового ИЛИ

Tags: массивы, битовые-операции, сжатие, rgb

Не могу понять можно ли вообще такое реализовать.
К примеру у нас есть массив из 100 3 байтовых чисел, то есть RGB. Нужно сжать все эти числа в новый массив, чтобы в итоге каждое из этих цветов можно было получить из нового массива с помощью побитового ИЛИ.
Пример на псевдокоде, того, чего именно я хочу получить:

```
array colors[100] = { /*... какие то цвета*/ };
array newColors[] = compress(colors); // новый массив
// и получаем нужный нам цвет
if(colors[33] == (newColors[1] | newColors[2] | newColors[8]))
    print("Работает");
```

Не важно даже если некоторые цвета будут в итоге не совсем теми, что были сначала.

Comment: А зачем? Если взять новый массив из 24 цветов, по одному на каждый бит, технически будет то что вы просили. Подходит?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Боже. . Я так долго думал над решением проблемы, а тут вот все как просто. Да подходит, спасибо.

Comment: Все-таки интересно, в чем тут замысел.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Делаю небольшую игру в консоли для Windows. Таблицы из 16 цветов не хватает. Сейчас обхожу этот момент находя среднее значение у похожих цветов, но все равно как то некрасиво получается.  Решил обойти более красивым путем. На каждом кадре около 128 цветов, сжимаем до 16, ставим в таблицу цветов, и используем уже побитовое ИЛИ, так как консоль позволяет такие манипуляции для слияния цветов, рисуем, и следующий кадр так же. Не знаю, получиться или нет, но надеюсь да.

Comment: А разве в Винду не завезли нормальный терминал с поддержкой true color?

Comment: @alexey-ten Да, знаю, завезли. Но так как я использую только те функции что поддерживаются старыми Windows, то это проблема. Впрочем, спасибо, что напомнили.